# How to create grouped vertices graphs with ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I'm discovering ArangoDB and I'm wondering if it is a suitable environment to work on graphs that display grouped nodes relations.

Here is a simple example :

Given a set of nodes :

```json
[ {
  "_key" : "a1",
  "group" : "a"
}, {
  "_key" : "a2",
  "group" : "a"
}, {
  "_key" : "b1",
  "group" : "b"
}, {
  "_key" : "b2",
  "group" : "b"
}, {
  "_key" : "c1",
  "group" : "c"
}, {
  "_key" : "c2",
  "group" : "c"
} ]
```

And their relations :

```json
[ {
  "_from" : "nodes/a1",
  "_to" : "nodes/b1",
  "qty" : 40
}, {
  "_from" : "nodes/a2",
  "_to" : "nodes/b2",
  "qty" : 50
}, {
  "_from" : "nodes/a1",
  "_to" : "nodes/c1",
  "qty" : 10
}, {
  "_from" : "nodes/a2",
  "_to" : "nodes/c1",
  "qty" : 50
}, {
  "_from" : "nodes/a2",
  "_to" : "nodes/c2",
  "qty" : 50
} ]
```

What is the best way for generating a graph that instead of displaying discrete nodes relations with the qty as an edge weight, will display  "group" agregated nodes  relations with the weight being the sum of "qty" of nodes inside each group.

So for instance, the graph would display a relation between the group "a" and "c" with a weight of 110.

Does it make any sense to use ArangoDB for such use cases ? And how to do it in a versatile way ?

Thanks for your help